# Ruby Which regular expression pattern to replace \n\n to \n string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string

```
Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++
```

i need to replace it becomes

```
Java \n c# \n c/c++
```

use regular expression in Ruby String

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use [`squeeze`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/squeeze) function of String class

```
[18] pry(main)> "Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++".squeeze("\n")
 => "Java \n c# \n c/c++"
```

However, it returns a new string where runs of the same character that occur in this set are replaced by a single character, So

```
 [18] pry(main)> "Java \n\n\n\n\n c# \n\n\n\n\n c/c++".squeeze("\n")
 => "Java \n c# \n c/c++"
```

Comment: Thoese work well for me

'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.squeeze!("\n")
'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.gsub!(/\n{1,}/)
Thanks all,

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to eliminate triple and so forth occurencies as well. In such a case the best option is to use the match counter:

```
#                                  ⇓⇓⇓⇓
'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.gsub /\\n{1,}/, '\n'
```

In this particular case, “one or more” has s syntactic sugar for it:

```
#                                  ⇓
'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.gsub /\\n+/, '\n'
```

If you are using Ruby2, there is `\R` match to match any combination of `\r` and `\n`.

To eliminate exactly two occurencies, one might use:

```
#                                  ⇓⇓⇓
'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.gsub /\\n{2}/, '\n'
```

And, finally, there is a function to remove multiple occurencies of `\n` from the string using [named matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) and backreferences:

```
def singlify s
  s.gsub /(?<sym>\\n)\g<sym>+/, '\k<sym>'
end

singlify 'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'
# Java \n c# \n c/c++'
```

Comment: Thoese work well for me

'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.squeeze!("\n")
'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.gsub!(/\n{1,}/)
Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

```
'Java \n\n c# \n\n c/c++'.gsub! /\\n\\n/, '\n'
```

Comment: `gsub("\n\n", "\n")` is much cleaner